# A general question on NP class problem

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, np-complete

I read the paper [*Certification-Cognizant Time-Triggered Scheduling of Mixed-Criticality Systems*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6121421/) (Baruah and Fohler, in *Proceedings of 32nd IEEE Real Time Systems Symposium*, 2011; see Section 6) which proves a particular problem to be NP-hard in strong sense and in PSPACE. Then they proposed a polynomial algorithm for the same problem which is sufficient but not necessary. For this algorithm, they claim that if the algorithm finds a solution then it is correct. Does this algorithm a verifier type algorithm? I am new to the field of theoretical computer science research. If anyone may explain this concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no, it doesn't follow from the claims you mention that this algorithm is a verifier in a meaningful use of the term.

The paper states:

> Our attempt here is to obtain a polynomial-time algorithm for
>   computing these tables that is sufficient but not necessary,
>   in the following sense. Our algorithm will not be able to
>   generate the scheduling tables for all TT-schedulable instances;
>   however, if the algorithm does generate scheduling tables for
>   an instance, then these tables are correct.

So, they claim to have a polynomial time algorithm that can provide a solution for a subset of all problem instances, but there are some cases for which this algorithm fails to provide a correct solution. Furthermore, they claim elsewhere that there is some characterization of this subset.

By contrast, a *polynomial time verifier* for a certain problem $X$ is an algorithm, that given an problem instance $I$ of $X$ and a certificate $C$, can prove whether the instance is a YES-instance or not in polynomial time. Usually, the certificate corresponds to some 'solution' that the verifier needs to verify correctness for.

So, the algorithm in this paper *can* be called a polynomial time verifier algorithm for the subset it solves in polynomial time *only*, as a polynomial algorithm that solves a problem is also a verifier. But, the claim that this algorithm is a verifier in this sense isn't useful, as it is a strictly weaker property (at least, if $P\neq NP$ ) than being an actual algorithm for the solution.